# R string with iterating int

Tags: r

I want to create a vector like "s1","s2",... automatically in R. What is the best way to achieve this? I tried the `rep` function, but no good result.

```
sampleLabels = c(rep('Control',46),rep('SLE',72))
```

It should be `'Control1','Control2',...,'SLE1','SLE2',...`

Comment: Do you know about the `paste` and `paste0` functions?

Comment: I'm trying apply(1:47,1,function(x){return(paste("Control",toString(x),sep=""))}) now, but it fails

Comment: Maybe try something like `c(paste0('Control', seq(46)), paste0('SLE', seq(72)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sprintf`, or `paste`/`paste0`, as suggested by @Dason:

```
c(sprintf("Control%d", 1:46), sprintf("SLE%d", 1:72))

c(paste0("Control", 1:46), paste0("SLE", 1:72))
```

Using `paste0(...)` is equivalent to `paste(..., sep = "")`; and since arguments are recycled as needed (`"Control"` and `"SLE"`) you don't need to use `sapply`, etc... in this case.